# Iphone browser cannot connect to SignalR server

Tags: iphone, signalr

I am trying to connect to a Signalr server that is running on local IIS of my PC. If I use a browser in my PC, I am able to connect and see in my console server that I have successfully connected and the ID is shown. But when I try accessing the site via Iphone, I am able to access the website but in my console signalr server, I can see that my Iphone is not able to connect i.e. the clientId does not show. I don't know which code to show you since the signalr server works with browser in my PC. It is just my iphone that cannot connect. Need your help.

Comment: There is nothing different about Safari on an iPhone with signalr. It's something else

Comment: I was able to create programs using signalr and was able to successfully communicate with mobile devices. I am just curious why this one isn’t communicating. I am thinking maybe Iphone or new versiin of signalr implemented something that I don’t know about.